# routing errors based on rail environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have subdomain routing setup like this

```
constraints :subdomain => 'my' do
  scope :module => 'my', :as => 'my' do
    scope :module => 'author', :as => 'author' do
      resources :modlette_author
    end
    resources :modlettes
    root :to => 'my#index'
  end
end
```

When I'm in a development environment, and in particular `config.cache_classes = false` the my_controller needs to sit in `app/controllers` and be defined like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout "my"
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index

  end
end
```

However in production when `config.cache_classes = true` rails wants the `my_controller` to be in `app/controllers/my` and be defined like this:

```
class My::MyController < ApplicationController
  layout "my"
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index

  end
end
```

Obviously it isn't practical to try and do both. Has anyone got any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While what Alex wrote was 100% correct there was a lot more wrong than just what Alex wrote. I ended up re-writting a large chunk for routes, and re-organising all the controller paths and controller names. I in re-writting all this from scratch I used the following links:

[Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

[Railscasts REST API Versioning](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `scope :module => 'my', :as => 'my' do` to `namespace :my, path: nil do` so it will work in development mode like in production.

Comment: No unfortunately not. With the production setting of `cache_classes = true` it returns the error: `uninitialized constant My::MyController`

Comment: For me it works fine with config settings you've provided. Rails 3.2.8

Comment: Are you restarting the rails server after making the change to the development environment file? For me it work if I don't but obviously it hasn't taken in the new setting.

Comment: The settings you've mentioned are default settings, so I looked on it only because you said about that. And it works for me with the code I've shown.

Comment: Thanks Alex. As I worked around the problem I found a few other things that may be related so I'm going to go back and rebuild the routes from scratch.